# Setting extraFields in rest api yii2

Tags: rest, yii2

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'field' => 'field',
    ];
}

public function extraFields()
{
    return [
        'users',
    ];
}
```

return:

```
{ "field": "field", "users": { "id": 1, "name": "user" } }
```

how to exclude id?

```
public function extraFields()
{
    return [
        'users' => function($model){
            return [
                'name' => $model->users->name,
            ];
        }
    ];
}
```

return:

```
{ "field": "field", "users": { "name": null } }
```

how to fill in the name field correctly or how to customize field output filtering?

Answer (score 0):

Option can be overwrite field() method in User model:

```
public function fields()
{
    $fields = parent::fields();
    if ($something) {
        unset($fields['id']);
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Comment: User model already has the following code
    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id' => 'id',
            'role' => 'role',
            'username' => 'username',
        ];
    }

Comment: So if you want hide "id" don't return it in field() method.